# Android Things Video Playback via GPU on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Was wondering if anyone have successfully play back HD video on Android Things platform on a Raspberry Pi 3.

My current experience is at 720p 30fps, videos are choppy. Frame rate dips occur often, and my Raspberry Pi 3 overheats during the process(even with heat-sinks). If my understanding is correct, the GPU on the Raspberry Pi is not being tap on for playback and that stress out the CPU which in turn cause overheating.

Thanks.